# Find density given characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions, density-function

Given,

> Characteristic Function $\displaystyle G(k) = \frac{\sin (ka)}{ka}$

Find the corresponding density,
I know the answer is

> $\displaystyle p(x) = \frac{1}{2a} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x \in (-a,a) $

I tried writing $\displaystyle \frac{\sin (ka)}{ka}$ as $\displaystyle\frac{e^{ika} - e^{-ika}}{2iak}$

And then using the inverse function but i am unable to integrate

I know,

> $\displaystyle p(x)  =  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(k) e^{-ikx} dk$

Can anyone pls help

Comment: @BGM Ty for edit I am new to mathjax and didn't have much time to go through the tutorial

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're right that that last integral is quite hard to do.  To show that $p$ is the corresponding density, you just need to calculate $\int_\mathbb{R} p(x) e^{it x} \,dx$ and show that it equals $\frac{\sin(ta)}{ta}$.

Comment: I can do that only if I know p(x) which I don't know prior to the question.I came across this question in a problem sheet, and the answer was mentioned as 1/2a Now I tried calculating G(k) from this and indeed i got the correct answer but the thing is what if I don't have p(x) = 1/2a.

I just posted the answer so that may help some find the answer

Comment: The best way that I'm aware of---in this case---is to recognize the characteristic function as corresponding to a uniform random variable.  There's no nice way to integral to get the density; in fact, the anti-derivative cannot be expressed in elementary functions.

Comment: Thanks for correction, Is there some method to go about for finding guess to probability density ?

Comment: It's a good idea to look at a table of characteristic functions when trying to go backwards.  Here's one from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Examples